# Set gdb breakpoint two lines after existing label

Tags: assembly, gdb

I have an assembly program with several labels on various lines. I need to set a `gdb` breakpoint two lines after a line with a label. How can I do that in `gdb` without adding an additional label to the program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gdb` supports adding breakpoints X bytes after a label, and since each instruction is 4 bytes, I only needed to do the following:

```
*&labelname + 8
```

Answer (score 1):

`b foo`, where `foo` is the line number in the source.

Comment: Is there a way to specify that it be two lines later than the label rather than specifying the line number itself?

Comment: Apparently `gdb` only supports offsets from the "current" line, not relative to any arbitrary label. Ie. `br +2` is valid but `br foo+2` isn't (well, it is, but it doesn't do what you want). You could write a small script that parses the line number out from a label and adds the offset before setting a breakpoint.